# Is there any solution for yaxis custom label on ployly.js timeseries chart?

Tags: javascript, plotly.js

```
  var dates = [
    "2019-08-16 11:30:45",
    "2019-08-16 11:45:30",
    "2019-08-18 10:30:50",
    "2019-08-19 10:45:46",
    "2019-08-20 13:14:26",
    "2019-08-21 14:26:34",
    "2019-08-22 16:18:48",
    "2019-08-23 17:35:53",
    "2019-08-24 19:04:07",
    "2019-08-25 20:22:23 "
  ];

  var data1 = [
    "500125",
    "600857",
    "500857",
    "700857",
    "500857",
    "800857",
    "500857",
    "900857",
    "500857",
    "10001"
  ];


  var data2 = [
    "400125",
    "500125",
    "200125",
    "500125",
    "300125",
    "500125",
    "100125",
    "350",
    "700125",
    "590"
  ];


  var trace1 = {
    type: "scatter",
    mode: "lines",
    name: 'INBOUND',
    x: dates,
    y: data1,
    line: {color: '#17BECF'}
  }

  var trace2 = {
    type: "scatter",
    mode: "lines",
    name: 'OUTBOUND',
    x: dates,
    y: data2,
    line: {color: '#7F7F7F'}
  }

  var data = [trace1,trace2];

  var layout = {
    title: 'Basic Time Series',
    xaxis: {
      title: 'DateTime',
      showgrid: true,
      zeroline: false
    },
    yaxis: {
      title: 'Metrics',
      showline: true,

    }
  };

  Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout, {responsive: true,scrollZoom: false});



  function formatBytes(bytes,decimals) {

    decimals = 1;
     if(bytes == 0) return '0 B/s';
     var k = 1000,
         dm = decimals <= 0 ? 0 : decimals || 2,
         sizes = ['B/s', 'KB/s', 'MB/s', 'GB/s', 'TB/s', 'PB/s', 'EB/s', 'ZB/s', 'YB/s'],
         i = Math.floor(Math.log(bytes) / Math.log(k));
         //console.log(sizes[i]);
         if(sizes[i] == 'KB/s' || sizes[i] == 'B/s'){
           dm = 0;
         }
     return (bytes / Math.pow(k, i)).toFixed(dm) + ' ' + sizes[i];
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure I understand what you mean by "custom label", but if you mean customizing the y-axis label, then yes.

To do this, instead of just specifying a string for `title`, you can create an object and set different properties for the font. For example:

```
title: {
    text: "Metrics",
    font: {
        family: "Courier New, monospace",
        size: 18,
        color: "#7f7f7f"
    }
}
```

I added this to your code and created a snippet. You can run it to see the results:

```js
var dates = [
  "2019-08-16 11:30:45",
  "2019-08-16 11:45:30",
  "2019-08-18 10:30:50",
  "2019-08-19 10:45:46",
  "2019-08-20 13:14:26",
  "2019-08-21 14:26:34",
  "2019-08-22 16:18:48",
  "2019-08-23 17:35:53",
  "2019-08-24 19:04:07",
  "2019-08-25 20:22:23 "
];

var data1 = [
  "500125",
  "600857",
  "500857",
  "700857",
  "500857",
  "800857",
  "500857",
  "900857",
  "500857",
  "10001"
];


var data2 = [
  "400125",
  "500125",
  "200125",
  "500125",
  "300125",
  "500125",
  "100125",
  "350",
  "700125",
  "590"
];


var trace1 = {
  type: "scatter",
  mode: "lines",
  name: 'INBOUND',
  x: dates,
  y: data1,
  line: {
    color: '#17BECF'
  }
}

var trace2 = {
  type: "scatter",
  mode: "lines",
  name: 'OUTBOUND',
  x: dates,
  y: data2,
  line: {
    color: '#7F7F7F'
  }
}

var data = [trace1, trace2];

var layout = {
  title: 'Basic Time Series',
  xaxis: {
    title: 'DateTime',
    showgrid: true,
    zeroline: false
  },
  yaxis: {
    showline: true,
    title: {
      text: 'Metrics',
      font: {
        family: 'Courier New, monospace',
        size: 18,
        color: '#7f7f7f'
      }
    }

  }
};

Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout, {
  responsive: true,
  scrollZoom: false
});



function formatBytes(bytes, decimals) {

  decimals = 1;
  if (bytes == 0) return '0 B/s';
  var k = 1000,
    dm = decimals <= 0 ? 0 : decimals || 2,
    sizes = ['B/s', 'KB/s', 'MB/s', 'GB/s', 'TB/s', 'PB/s', 'EB/s', 'ZB/s', 'YB/s'],
    i = Math.floor(Math.log(bytes) / Math.log(k));
  //console.log(sizes[i]);
  if (sizes[i] == 'KB/s' || sizes[i] == 'B/s') {
    dm = 0;
  }
  return (bytes / Math.pow(k, i)).toFixed(dm) + ' ' + sizes[i];
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
<div id="myDiv">
</div>
```

If you meant something different than this, please clarify your question.